# html dropdownlist cannot type until clicked on

Tags: html, yii

I have tried this in multiple browsers and have done searches for this but have not been able to find a solution.

So here is the problem.  I have CHtml::dropDownLists on my page.  When you tab to that  you can sometimes just type to change to an option that is with in it but there are other times where you have to actually click on that  before you can start typing to change.  Granted once you click on it you can change it but I need to have more of a hands off mouse control.

I was curious if this was based on how the browser placed items with its DOM or if it is something with Yii.

Any thoughts, pointer, hidden websites about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could be because the dropdown is missing focus

Comment: But what would be causing it to lose focus when you tab to it.  Could it be because of what Yii puts for verification?  I have checked and client verification is not turned on, I am doing it all server side.  Also just for an FYI the select does change to the accepted green when tabbed to it.

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you can provide an online demo and steps to reproduce the problem.